# SQL запрос составить не получается

Tags: mysql, sql

Помогите составить правильный SQL запрос.

```
UPDATE general_setting
SET total_orders = COUNT(*) FROM TABLE orders;
```

мне нужно чтобы в таблице `general_setting`  столбцу `total_orders` присвоилась цифра равная сумме всех значений таблицы `orders`

Comment: `UPDATE general_setting SET total_orders = (select COUNT(*) FROM TABLE orders);`?

Comment: увы но не срабатывает такой запрос..

Comment: TABLE лишнее в синтаксисе запроса

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders правильно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если включён safeupdate не даст изменить значение в таблице без указания PrimaryKey в параметре WHERE

```
  SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
  UPDATE general_setting SET total_orders = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders);
```

Comment: благодарочка!)  все заработало))